OpenAPI documentation for C# class
I am using .NET 6, and my folder structure is module based. Each module should be released as a nuget package. Also, each module has a moduleName.Client.cs file. I want to generate an OpenAPI documentation for each client, which basically is methods with requests and response.
public class TestClient 
{
    public async Task<TestObject> ListAsync (RequestObject request) 
    {
        var testResponse = await QueryService.QueryAsync(request);     
        return testResponse;
    }
}

I have tried creating a generator project, which uses nswag:
using System.Diagnostics;
 
var modules = new[] { "Test" };

foreach (var module in modules)
{
    GenerateOpenApiDocumentation(module);
}
 
void GenerateOpenApiDocumentation(string module)
{
    var projectPath = Path.Combine("..", "Modules", module, $"{module}.csproj");
    var outputPath = Path.Combine("..", "Modules", module, "swagger.json");
 
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = $"tool run swagger tofile --output {outputPath} {projectPath} v1",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
 
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
 
    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error generating OpenAPI documentation for {module}: {error}");
    }
}

My problem is that I get the following error:

Error generating OpenAPI documentation for Test: Cannot find tool in the manifest file that has a command named "swagger".


All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what problem you're having. What troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic; asking us to write the program for you is off-topic.

Sorry! Did update the problem description.

does it work, if you execute the same command (in the same directory) via a command line?
